# Error converting data type nvarchar to Datetime While Calling Store Procedure in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass datetime value to the store procedure of mssql but getting this error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to  datetime. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Here is the code:

```
fromDate = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
toDate = datetime(2022, 12, 31)
dealershipId = request.GET['dealershipId']
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"EXEC proc_LoadJobCardbyDateRange [@Fromdate={fromDate}, @Todate={toDate}, @DealershipId={dealershipId}]")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

I have tried to pass datetime object in order to execute store procedure. I also tried to pass datetime as string but the same error persists. I also tried different formats but it didn't work as mentioned in some solutions that I have searched for.

Also,

```
cursor.execute("EXEC proc_LoadJobCardbyDateRange @Fromdate="+fromDate+", @Todate='2022-12-31 00:00:00', @DealershipId="+dealershipId)
```

If I pass the date as it is shown in `@Todate`, it works fine but if I pass it as a variable like I did in `@Fromdate` case, it throws an error which is `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")` and if I try to pass it as a datetime object then I got this error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str`

Please guide me as to why I am having this issue and what's the correct solution to this can be?

Comment: You are enclosing the parameters  in brackets, so you are sending the whole thing as one string type parameter. Remove the brackets.

Comment: @DouadyRabbit I tried removing the `[ ]` brackets too but got this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")` and format of datetime is `2022-12-31 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are building your string seems wrong, searching let me to change your string to this:

```
cursor.Execute('EXEC LoadJobCardbyDateRange @Fromdate = ?, @Todate=?, @DealershipId=?', fromDate, '2022-12-31', dealershipId)
```

See this link: [Django execute stored procedure - different data types, multiple parameters and different columns from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213197/django-execute-stored-procedure-different-data-types-multiple-parameters-and)

Comment: my string is fine, because it doesn't throw any error if I pass int or varchar value. I get error when I try to pass date in a variable like `fromdate='2022-12-31'`, it throws error at `-`, I don't know why but if I pass the date directly `2022-12-31`, it works fine.

Comment: Could you please post the signature of your procedure? or the entire procedure if is not too long.

Comment: I manage to do it, the issue was with the value in the database.